# changing text size of a selected spinner item

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-spinner

I am accessing a spinner inside an xml.And also using a customized adapter with another xml containig a textview alone.Now the problem is am not able to change the size of the selected spinner text.am able to change the list items inside a spinner by changing the textsize property which i defined in the styles sheet.The page involves 2 files and am posting what are all i have in my App.

Styles sheet:
          32sp

Simple_spinner_Item(Used in adapter):

```
       <TextView    
        android:id="@+id/spinnerText"      
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
         android:padding="3dp"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"         
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>
```

My Page Xml:

```
    <Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spin1"
    android:layout_width="500dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="68dp"
    android:layout_y="328dp"/>
```

My Java code:

```
     public void page2_load()
     {

        Spinner spn1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spin1);   

         String[] items1 = {"SELECT","01 - I do / myself","02 - Partner / friend        /        parents / other family member","03 - You pay, but claim back all business calls","04 - Business pays for calls","05 - Business pays business calls, you pay personal call","06 - Other","99 - Dont know"};
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new  ArrayAdapter<String>this,android.R.layout.preference_category,items1);                         adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spn1.setAdapter(adapter1);
       }
```

any ideas or  solutions for my problem?

Suresh

Answer (score 1):

simple to add this in the spinner event

```
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor") @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {

            ((TextView) rent.getChildAt(0)).setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
            ((TextView) parent.getChildAt(0)).setTextSize(5);



enter code here
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });



}

public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

}
```

};

Answer (score 0):

When you're creating `ArrayAdapter` override it's `getView(...)` method, e.g.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>this,ndroid.R.layout.preference_category, items) {
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        TextView textView = (TextView)view.findViewById(android.R.id.title);
        // Do your stuff with that TextView.

        return view.
    }
};
```

I'm not very sure if `getView(...)` is written correctly, you may have to debug it a bit. Hope this helps!

Answer (score -2):

Use the following attribute `android:textSize="20dp"`.

Either in `Spinner` **or** `Textview widget`.

Or

you can draw from `res-> drawable`

Comment: This didn't work for me. It seems that android:textSize does nothing.